# Does APNS return a retry-after header when 429/503/500

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to know if the iOS push notification server returns a retry-after header when response is 503/500/429

There seems nothing specific in the documentation, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/handling_notification_responses_from_apns)

unlike FCM, which clearly states that retry-after should be respected. [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode)